# run script to generate new image size from existing images using imagemagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave with ImageMagick for my Rails application.  I'd like to run a script to generate a new image version of all existing images.  What would be the best way to do this?  I have not written scripts for my Rails app before.

I created a version in my uploader.rb file:

```
  version :square_thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [105, 105]
  end
```

In my rails console, I tried to create new versions doing the following:

```
Image.all.each do |image|
    image.recreate_version!(:square_thumb)
end
```

But I get the error: **NoMethodError: undefined method `recreate_version!' for ImagePathUploader:0x007fe7f62ba4e0**

Does anyone have advice for how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, I created a method in my image_path_uploader.rb file:

```
   def add_square_thumb
    recreate_versions!(:square_thumb)
   end
```

From the console, I can then do

```
Image.all.each do |image|
    image.image_path.add_square_thumb
end
```